# Passing two arguments for the 'optimize' function in R

Tags: r, function

I have a function like below in R:

```
f<-function(a, x){
    return(a*sin(x))
}
```

I want to find the maximum of this function using the `optimize` function as below:

```
optimize(f, interval, maximum=TRUE)
```

However, I am getting an error saying `argument "x" is missing, with no default`. I know it is because the function should have only one argument. But I need to pass the value of `a` to the function. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```r
f <- function(a, x){
  return(a*sin(x))
}

optimize(f, c(0, 2*pi), maximum=TRUE, a = 2)

#> $maximum
#> [1] 1.570794
#> 
#> $objective
#> [1] 2
```